# Dart - Await all async tasks in a for loop

Tags: for-loop, asynchronous, dart, async-await, for-await

I have a list of Objects in Dart and I want to perform an asynchronous operation with every one of these objects. After all of the asynchronous operations have finished, I want to perform a final operation. I am currently doing this with code that looks like following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myObjectList.length; i++) {
  await myAsynchronousOperation(myObjectList[i]);
}
doFinalOperation();
```

While this technically works, I assume that it is inefficient because the for loop will wait for the first asynchronous operation to finish before starting the second one. So from my understanding we end up synchronously firing asynchronous operations, which can't be the intention of asynchronous programming.

My question therefore is if it is somehow possible to fire all asynchronous operations at once, then wait until they are all finished, and then finally perform the final operation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`Future.wait`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/wait.html) to wait for multiple in-flight `Future`s:

```dart
await Future.wait([
  for (int i = 0; i < myObjectList.length; i++)
    myAsynchronousOperation(myObjectList[i]),
]);
doFinalOperation();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It raises two additional questions for me, however:

1. Android Studio gives me the following warning: "The for, if, and spread elements weren't supported until version 2.3.0, but this code is required to be able to run on earlier versions." What does this mean in this context?

2. This code does not work when using the for loop with brackets. Following error: "The argument type 'List<Set<Set<Future<void>>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Future<dynamic>>'." If I wanted to insert an if condition within the for loop, that does not seem possible.

Comment: 1. Modify your `pubspec.yaml` file and specify a higher minimum Dart version.  Otherwise tools assume that your code is intended to remain compatible with old versions of the Dart SDK. 2. The code should work if `myAsynchronousOperation` returns a `Future` and if you typed it as I gave in my example.  Note that this is the special collection-`for` syntax and that you *cannot* add curly braces (`{` and `}`) in the loop body, as that would create a `Set` literal.

Comment: And yes, you can use `if` within a collection-`for` loop.  It's called [collection-`if`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators).

Comment: Here's what got added in 2.3: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#230---2019-05-08

Comment: If `myAsynchronousOperation` is really already a function, then this is one of the few places where I'd probably *not* use the new list literal, and just do `await Future.wait(myObjectList.map(myAsynchronousOperation));`.