# How I can reduce the time of a for loop in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I have a method called getNearByPlaces(), then I have for loop that iterates over each place_id, and send a request to google API, to get the name of the place_id,
so this operation takes around 15 seconds, how I can make it faster?

```
Future<void> getNearByPlaces(double latitude, double longitude) async {
    List results = [];
    List placesId = [];
    List nearbyPlaces = [];
    String nearbyUrl =
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${latitude},${longitude}&radius=500&key=${mapKey}";
    var nearbyResponse =
        await RequestAssistant.getRequest(Uri.parse(nearbyUrl));
    if (nearbyResponse == "Failed.") {
      return;
    }
    results = nearbyResponse["results"];
    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      placesId.add(results[i]['place_id']);
      String placeDetailsUrl =
          "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=${results[i]['place_id']}&key=$mapKey";
      var response =
          await RequestAssistant.getRequest(Uri.parse(placeDetailsUrl));

      if (response == "Failed.") {
        return;
      }
      if (response["status"] == "OK") {
        await nearbyPlaces.add(response["result"]["name"]);
      }
    }
    print(nearbyPlaces);
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("nearbyPlaces")
        .doc(uid)
        .set({'nearbyPlaces': nearbyPlaces});
  }
```

Comment: If each loop iteration is independent (i.e., does not depend on results from previous iterations), instead of waiting for each iteration to complete before starting the next iteration, you can collect all of the `Future`s in a `List` and use `Future.wait`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/65133090/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just use only name in the detail result, you don't need to query again by 'place_id' because I found that there are more information in 'nearbysearch' API results.

For example, icon, name, photos and so on like below.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "next_page_token" : "CpQCAgEAAFxg8o-eU7_uKn7Yqjana-HQIx1hr5BrT4zBaEko29ANsXtp9mrqN0yrKWhf-y2PUpHRLQb1GT-mtxNcXou8TwkXhi1Jbk-ReY7oulyuvKSQrw1lgJElggGlo0d6indiH1U-tDwquw4tU_UXoQ_sj8OBo8XBUuWjuuFShqmLMP-0W59Vr6CaXdLrF8M3wFR4dUUhSf5UC4QCLaOMVP92lyh0OdtF_m_9Dt7lz-Wniod9zDrHeDsz_by570K3jL1VuDKTl_U1cJ0mzz_zDHGfOUf7VU1kVIs1WnM9SGvnm8YZURLTtMLMWx8-doGUE56Af_VfKjGDYW361OOIj9GmkyCFtaoCmTMIr5kgyeUSnB-IEhDlzujVrV6O9Mt7N4DagR6RGhT3g1viYLS4kO5YindU6dm3GIof1Q",
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.867217,
               "lng" : 151.195939
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/cafe-71.png",
         "name" : "Biaggio Cafe - Pyrmont",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 600,
               "html_attributions" : [],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAAmWmj0BqA0Jorm1_vjAvx1n6c7ZNBxyY-U9x99-oNyOxvMjDlo2npJzyIq7c3EK1YyoNXdMFDcRPzwLJtBzXAwCUFDGo_RtLRGBPJTA2CoerPdC5yvT2SjfDwH4bFf5MrznB0_YWa4Y2Qo7ABtAxgeBIQv46sGBwVNJQDI36Wd3PFYBoUTlVXa0wn-zRITjGp0zLEBh8oIBE",
               "width" : 900
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJIfBAsjeuEmsRdgu9Pl1Ps48",
         "price_level" : 1,
         "rating" : 3.4,
         "reference" : "ChIJIfBAsjeuEmsRdgu9Pl1Ps48",
         "types" : [ "cafe", "bar", "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont"
      },
```

So you just iterate 'nearbysearch' result and making 'nearbyPlaces' data.

```
...

results = nearbyResponse["results"];
    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      placesId.add(results[i]['place_id']);
      nearbyPlaces.add(results[i]['name');
    }
    print(nearbyPlaces);
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! you saved my life! it now takes only 1 second ! I didn't know I can take the name from the first API only, although I opened the JSON files, but didn't notice the name